# Sorting TableView By Location?

Tags: sorting, uitableview, location

I want to sort my tableview cells by nearest location to the user.
Let's say i have 14 stores & i want to sort it by location.
Is there any example for doing something like this ?

Thanks!

---

Yes,
I have a tableview with 14 cells & i put names of 14 stores form plist in those cells with navigation control to other views with details (from the plist too).
The 14 stores are all over the country & i want to sort them by place according to my location in the country (with the assistant of the GPS of course)
I want that the neares store will be at the top of the table.

This is my sort code that i need to use but i can't figure it out how & where to integrate it with the table.
For everyone who need that - feel free to use this code :).. alot of people need that:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareDistance:(id)obj 
{
    CLLocation* loc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:32.066157 longitude:34.777821];

    StoreAnnotation* operand1 = self;
    StoreAnnotation* operand2 = obj;

    CLLocation* operand1Location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:operand1.coordinate.latitude longitude:operand1.coordinate.longitude];

    CLLocationDistance distanceOfLocFromOperand1 = [loc distanceFromLocation:operand1Location];
    NSLog(@"The distance of loc from op1 = %f meters", distanceOfLocFromOperand1);

    CLLocation* operand2Location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:operand2.coordinate.latitude longitude:operand2.coordinate.longitude];

    CLLocationDistance distanceOfLocFromOperand2 = [loc distanceFromLocation:operand2Location];
    NSLog(@"The distance of loc from op2 = %f meters", distanceOfLocFromOperand2);

    if (distanceOfLocFromOperand1 < distanceOfLocFromOperand2) 
    {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }

    else if (distanceOfLocFromOperand1 > distanceOfLocFromOperand2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;

    else return NSOrderedSame;

}
```

It will be great if someone could help me with that..
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so i got the code that doing the job with the cells together with the sorting code below.
I hope it will help to a lot of developers that need that.
Thanks for trying to help :)

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrayFromPlist count];
    NSLog(@"Array SIZE = %d",[arrayFromPlist count]);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}   
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    StoreAnnotation* tmpSt = [[Storage sharedStorage].sortedStoresArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = tmpSt.title;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    double lat1=[lat doubleValue];
    double lon1=[lon doubleValue];
    CLLocation *userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:lon1];
    CLLocation *distForIndex = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:tmpSt.coordinate.latitude longitude:tmpSt.coordinate.longitude];
    CLLocationDistance distance = [userLocation distanceFromLocation:distForIndex];
    NSLog(@"DISTANCE FOR CELL %d - %f",indexPath.row, distance);
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f kmh", distance/1000]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
    UIView* backgroundView = [[ UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = [ UIColor blackColor ];
    cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
    for ( UIView* view in cell.contentView.subviews ) 
    {
        view.backgroundColor = [ UIColor blackColor ];
    }

return cell;
}
```

Comment: when you use >double lat1=[lat doubleValue]; and >double lon1=[lon doubleValue]; are those member properties to your UITableViewClass?